# Parsing URLs that need authentication, cookies - python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, url, authentication, cookies, beautifulsoup

https://example.net/users/101

The login page has a form with username & password. I used both urllib.request & http.cookiejar. I'm still not able to extract contents from that URL. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Code using urllib.request:

```
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener()
print(opener.open('http://username:password@example.net/').read())
```

Code using http.cookiejar:

```
import requests,http.cookiejar,urllib.request,os
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password})
binary_data = login_data.encode('ascii')
resp = opener.open('https://example.net/users/101', binary_data)
print(resp)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `mechanize` 
Refer: `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/`
Help: `http://swizec.com/blog/scraping-with-mechanize-and-beautifulsoup/swizec/5039`

Comment: Thanks. http://stockrt.github.io/p/handling-html-forms-with-python-mechanize-and-BeautifulSoup/ - I found this helpful!